# ElasticSearch with Docker and Traefic

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

When I will run elasticsearch with docker and traefic (With SSL encryption).
Than I can't connect to elasticsearch via domain.

When I remove all traefic things in the docker-compose by the elastic search tham it works over the IP and http.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

`
version: "3.7"

networks:
traefik:
external: true
search:

services:
elasticsearch:
image: elasticsearch:7.16.2
container_name: elasticsearch
environment:
- xpack.security.enabled=false
- discovery.type=single-node
- ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
- ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
volumes:
- elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
labels:
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.elastic_search.rule=Host(`se.mydomain.xyz`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.elastic_search.entrypoints.websecure"
- "traefik.http.services.elastic_search.loadbalancer.server.port=9200"
ports:
- 9200:9200
- 9300:9300
networks:
- search

kibana:
image: kibana:7.16.2
container_name: kibana
labels:
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.kibana_search.rule=Host(`kibana.mydomain.xyz`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.kibana_search.entrypoints.websecure"
- "traefik.http.services.kibana_search.loadbalancer.server.port=5601"
#ports:
#- 5601:5601
environment:
ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]'
networks:
- search
- traefik

volumes:
elasticsearch-data:
driver: local

`

Has anyone a idea for a solution?